# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work pr

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio version - 4.2.0.24. When I create a new project in it, it says **Gradle Project sync failed.**

It also shows an error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'ChatTutorial'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
> Searched in the following locations:
> -https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
> -
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
> Required by:
> project :
>
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Please help with this problem!!!

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: What is a proxy? and how to see whether I am behind a proxy?

Comment: go to : file -> setting -> appearance & behavior -> system setting -> HTTP Proxy